# How to use react redux to show data that comes from an api inside an option select?

Tags: reactjs, redux, axios, material-ui, redux-toolkit

After making the request for a locale API, I have to get the response data and put it inside a select. To find out if the request was ok, I made a console.log (DATA STATE) and got the following return:

```
DATA STATE 
{data: Array(27), status: 200, statusText: "OK", headers: AxiosHeaders, config: Object…}
```

I tried to map the state select inside the component (states->index.js) , however, no information is returned. My goal is that when selecting a state (data.nome) (states->index.js) the cities of state appear in the component (city->index.js).

**Code statesSlice.js**

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { FormControl, InputLabel, MenuItem, Select } from "@mui/material";
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from "react-redux";
import { getStates } from "../states/statesSlice";

export const SelectState = () => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const states = useSelector((state) => state.states.dataState);
  const [stateSelected, setStateSelected] = useState("");

  useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(getStates());
  }, [dispatch]);

  const handleChange = (event) => {
    dispatch(setStateSelected(event.target.value));
  };

  return (
    <FormControl sx={{ m: 1, minWidth: 120 }} size="small">
      <InputLabel id="demo-select-small">State</InputLabel>
      <Select
        labelId="demo-select-small"
        id="demo-select-small"
        value={stateSelected}
        label="estados"
        onChange={handleChange}
      >
        <MenuItem disabled>Select a state</MenuItem>
        {states.length > 0 &&
          states.map((item) => (
            <MenuItem key={item.id} value={item.sigla}>
              {item.nome}
            </MenuItem>
          ))}
      </Select>
    </FormControl>
  );
};
```

What can I try next? I'm new to Redux. I already created the store.js, slices and provider in index.js.

Comment: UF should be a NUMBER, right?

Comment: Am almost there!

Comment: Sure, https://codesandbox.io/s/createasyncthunk-createslice-redux-forked-9qwene?file=/src/features/states/index.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add `setState` function this way:

```
export const setState = createAsyncThunk(
  "state/setState",
  async (selectedState, { rejectWithValue }) => {
    try {
      return selectedState;
    } catch (err) {
      return rejectWithValue([], err);
    }
  }
);
```

And in the `reducer`s list,

```
    builder.addCase(setState.fulfilled, (state, action) => {
      state.selectedState = action.payload;
    });
```

And then call the `setState` function to set the selected state:

```
dispatch(setState(e.target.value));
```

The same approach has been applied to `getCities` as well.

The code is a bit lengthy, but I guess this might be better for the maintenance and expansion of the codebase in the future.

The working demo is here: https://codesandbox.io/s/createasyncthunk-createslice-redux-forked-9qwene?file=/src/features/states/statesSlice.js

Comment: I started in redux one week ago. I have a question, the code:
`middleware: (getDefaultMiddleware) => getDefaultMiddleware()` work for what?

Comment: It's not needed, in fact

Answer (score 0):

There's a couple of things going on here. First, your dispatch within `states/index.js` is broken - `dispatch` takes a plain object, either created through an action creator or a simple literal.

So this...

```
const handleChange = (event) => {
    dispatch(setStateSelected(event.target.value));
};
```

Should be something like

```
const handleChange = (event) => {
    dispatch({ action:"state/setState", payload: event.target.value });
};
```

Also, within your thunks your getting an error because your trying to put the entire response in the store (headers and all).
e.g. Instead of

```
return response // represents the whole response with metadata
```

You just want

```
return response.data // the array of states
```